# How to add document which property missing but present on mongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need save this document but mongoose Schema contains field not existed in the object. In case client uses old API I want to support both variants.

```
   {
      "user": "someUser",
      "password": "qwerty",
   }

   const userSchema = new Schema({
          user: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          },
          password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          },
         preferences: {
           banned: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
         }
        }
   })


   User.findOneAndUpdate({
        user: req.body.user
    }, {
        password: req.body.password
        preferences: {
            banned: true
        }
    }, {
        upsert: true,
        new: true,
        setDefaultsOnInsert: true
    }
```

Comment: can u please explain which is old "variant" and what is "new"?

Comment: Old has no `preferences` property, new does have.

Comment: then you have to check before updating whether prefrences available or not, if it is then only update prefrences

Comment: Is any way to set `preferences` default to empty object `{}` and Mongoose will not create it at least if not `minimize: false` ?.